# Synchronous Call AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, synchronous

METHOD 1

```
{
    var myform = getForm();
    var myVar = $sce.trustAsHtml(myForm);
}
```

METHOD 2

```
var getForm = function () {
    var form = "";
    //API CALL here using custom service
    .then(
    function (response) {
          form = //processing here
    },
    function (response) {
    }
    return form;
};
```

In below scenario I am calling `getForm()` method and need processed data from form variable. But it always return empty before processing.

How can I make this call sync so that I can `getForm()` return the processed data and returns to `method 1`

Comment: `getForm` should return the promise from the custom service, and not do `then` in itself.  do the `then` in method 1.

Comment: You can't. You need to understand and accept that an API call is asynchronous, and deal with it. The method can not return data. It can return a promise, or an observable of data, but not the data.

Comment: Read [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deal with promise here:

```
var myform = getForm().then(
    (form) => {
       $sce.trustAsHtml($sce.valueOf(form))
    },
    (error) => {
       // getForm - fail
    });
```

METHOD 2 - return promise instead form value

```
var getForm = function () {
    return //API CALL here using custom service
};
```

Or even easier:

```
yourService.serviceMethod().then(
    (form) => {
       $sce.trustAsHtml(form)
    },
    (error) => {
       // getForm - fail
});
```

Comment: thanks it helped. only change I need to made was $sce.trustAsHtml($sce.valueOf(form))